# How to use web worker inside a for loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Following is the code to create a 2d matrix in javascript:

```
function Create2DArray(rows) {
  var arr = [];

  for (var i=0;i<rows;i++) {
     arr[i] = [];
  }

  return arr;
}
```

now I have a couple of 2d matrices inside an array:

```
const matrices = []
for(let i=1; i<10000; i++){
   matrices.push(new Create2DArray(i*100))
}

// I'm just mocking it here. In reality we have data available in matrix form.
```

I want to do operations on each matrix like this:

```
for(let i=0; i<matrices.length; i++){
   ...domeAnythingWithEachMatrix()
}
```

& since it will be a computationally expensive process, I would like to do it via a web worker so that the main thread is not blocked.

I'm using `paralleljs` for this purpose since it will provide nice api for multithreading. (Or should I use the native Webworker? Please suggest.)

```
update() {
for(let i=0; i<matrices.length; i++){
   var p = new Parallel(matrices[i]);

                            p.spawn(function (matrix) {
                                return doanythingOnMatrix(matrix)
    // can be anything like transpose, scaling, translate etc...
                            }).then(function (matrix) {
                                return back so that I can use those values to update the DOM or directly update the DOM here.
    // suggest a best way so that I can prevent crashes and improve performance.
                            });
}
requestAnimationFrame(update)
}
```

So my question is what is the best way of doing this?

Is it ok to use a new `Webworker` or `Parallel` instance inside a for loop?
Would it cause memory issues?

Or is it ok to create a global instance of `Parallel` or `Webworker` and use it for manipulating each matrix?

**Or suggest a better approach.**

***I'm using `Parallel.js` for as alternative for `Webworker`***

Is it ok to use parallel.js for multithreading? (Or do I need to use the native Webworker?)

**In reality, the matrices would contain position data & this data is processed by the Webworker or parallel.js instance behind the scenes and returns the processed result back to the main app, which is then used to draw items / update canvas**

**UPDATE** **NOTE**

Actually, this is an animation. So it will have to be updated for each matrix during each tick.

Currently, I'm creating a new Instance of parallel inside the for loop. I fear that this would be a non conventional approach. Or it would cause memory leaks. I need the best way of doing this. Please suggest.

**UPDATE**

**This is my example:**

Comment: Since you're using ParallelJS, why do you still need a loop? Can't you just do `var p = new Parallel(matrices); p.map(doanythingOnMatrix).then(function (results) { console.log(results); });` ?

Comment: No actually this is an animation. So it will have to updated for each matrix during each ```tick```

Comment: How can I return the processed data so that I can use it to update the DOM. (or directly update the DOM inside the ```then``` block?

Comment: Currently I'm creating a new Instance of parallel inside the for loop. I fear that this would be a non conventional approach. Or it would cause memory leaks. I need the best way of doing this. Please suggest.

Comment: Currently even if I use parallel js and compare with native javascript approach..... I don't see any difference. I fear I'm doing it wrong!!

Comment: Oh ok. Well, yes, creating a new instance of Parallel for each matrix is overkill, and kind of defeats the purpose of Parallel, which is meant to do multiple things at once. I see that they don't provide a way to get the data while there are still items in the queue, so now I get why you used a loop. But I guess a better way would be to work in chunks, to take advantage of having multiple workers. E.g. You pass it a dozen matrices at a time, so that you can use the results as they come back

Comment: So you are suggesting me to create a single global instance and use it multiple times for each matrices inside  the for loop??

Comment: Or can you please show me some code suggesting the best way of doing this.?
Consider this like matrix manipulation (matrix manipulation is oftenly used with image processing and graphics)... consider each matrix as single image and so on... (In my case these matrices are not real images but are made by combining html5 canvas shapes & each of those singleton objects attributes are stored as a matrix for each)

Comment: I'll give it a shot, maybe someone else will have a better idea. Give me a couple of minutes, I'll try posting an answer

Comment: Great Thanks for your time and patience.!

Comment: As currently written, this question is far too broad and opinion-based. You ask several questions, almost all of which are "is it okay", which is something only you can answer. If you have code to share, please share it here on Stack Overflow, not only on external sites.

Answer (score 0):

Following our discussion in the comments, here is an attempt at using chunks. The data is processed by groups of 10 (a ***chunk***), so that you can receive their results regularly, and we only start the animation after receiving 200 of them (***buffer***) to get a head start (think of it like a video stream). But these values may need to be adjusted depending on how long each matrix takes to process.

That being said, you added details afterwards about the lag you get. I'm not sure if this will solve it, or if the problem lays in your canvas `update` function. That's just a path to explore:

```js
/*
 * A helper function to process data in chunks
 */
async function processInChunks({ items, processingFunc, chunkSize, bufferSize, onData, onComplete }) {
  const results = [];
  // For each group of {chunkSize} items
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i += chunkSize) {
    // Process this group in parallel
    const p = new Parallel( items.slice(i, i + chunkSize) );
    // p.map is no a real Promise, so we create one
    // to be able to await it
    const chunkResults = await new Promise(resolve => {
      return p.map(processingFunc).then(resolve);
    });
    // Add to the results
    results.push(...chunkResults);
    // Pass the results to a callback if we're above the {bufferSize}
    if (i >= bufferSize && typeof onData === 'function') {
      // Flush the results
      onData(results.splice(0, results.length));
    }
  }
  // In case there was less data than the wanted {bufferSize},
  // pass the results anyway
  if (results.length) {
    onData(results.splice(0, results.length));
  }
  if (typeof onComplete === 'function') {
    onComplete();
  }
}

/*
 * Usage
 */
// For the demo, a fake matrix Array
const matrices = new Array(3000).fill(null).map((_, i) => i + 1);
const results = [];
let animationRunning = false;

// For the demo, a function which takes time to complete
function doAnythingWithMatrix(matrix) {
  const start = new Date().getTime();
  while (new Date().getTime() - start < 30) { /* sleep */ }
  return matrix;
}

processInChunks({
  items: matrices,
  processingFunc: doAnythingWithMatrix,
  chunkSize: 10, // Receive results after each group of 10
  bufferSize: 200, // But wait for at least 200 before starting to receive them
  onData: (chunkResults) => {
    results.push(...chunkResults);
    if (!animationRunning) { runAnimation(); }
  },
  onComplete: () => {
    console.log('All the matrices were processed');
  }
});

function runAnimation() {
  animationRunning = results.length > 0;
  if (animationRunning) {
    updateCanvas(results.shift());
    requestAnimationFrame(runAnimation);
  }
}

function updateCanvas(currentMatrixResult) {
  // Just for the demo, we're not really using a canvas
  canvas.innerHTML = `Frame ${currentMatrixResult} out of ${matrices.length}`;
  info.innerHTML = results.length;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/paralleljs@1.0/lib/parallel.js"></script>

<h1 id="canvas">Buffering...</h1>
<h3>(we've got a headstart of <span id="info">0</span> matrix results)</h3>
```

Comment: On Safari... it is just showing Buffering... it's not doing anything!